# Struts 2 editable grid,want to take a form value which is out side the grid while adding form data via + icon/delete icon not picking property values

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have a struts 2 editable grid

```
<s:url id="attrAssignmentGridUrl"
                        action="populateAttributeAssignmentGrid">
                    </s:url>
                    <s:url id="attrAssignmentEditGridUrl"
                        action="saveOrupdateAttributeAssignment" />
                    <sjg:grid id="attrAssignmentGrid" href="%{attrAssignmentGridUrl}"
                        dataType="json" name="attrAssignmentGrid"
                        formIds="attributeSetupForm"
                        reloadTopics="reloadAttrAssignmentGrid"
                        onSelectRowTopics="attrAssignmentRowSelect" pager="true"
                        rowList="100,500,1000" rowNum="10" rownumbers="false"
                        navigator="true"
                        navigatorRefresh="false"
                        navigatorSearch="false"
                        navigatorAdd="true"
                        navigatorAddOptions="{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:true}"
                        navigatorEdit="true"
                        navigatorEditOptions="{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false}"
                        navigatorView="false"
                        navigatorDelete="true"
                        navigatorDeleteOptions="{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:true}"
                        gridModel="attributeAssignmentList" gridview="true"
                        editinline="true" editurl="%{attrAssignmentEditGridUrl}"
                        viewrecords="true" onEditInlineSuccessTopics="oneditsuccess"
                        requestType="post" onPagingTopics="pagingAttrAssignmentGrid">

                        <sjg:gridColumn name="ownerId" index="ownerId"
                            id="ownerId" editable="true" title="Owner Id" align="center"
                            sortable="false" edittype="text" search="false" width="150" />

                        <sjg:gridColumn name="assetId" index="assetId"
                            id="assetId" title="Asset Id" align="center" editable="true"
                            sortable="false" edittype="text" search="false" width="150" />

                        <sjg:gridColumn name="value" index="value"
                            id="value" title="Value" align="center" editable="true"
                            sortable="false" edittype="text" search="false" width="150" />

                        <sjg:gridColumn name="createdBy"
                            index="createdBy" id="createdBy" title="Created By"
                            align="center" editable="true" sortable="false" edittype="text"
                            search="false" width="150" />

                        <sjg:gridColumn name="lastUpdatedBy"
                            index="lastUpdatedBy" id="grdlastUpdatedBy"
                            title="Last Updated By" align="center" sortable="false"
                            editable="true" edittype="text" search="false" width="150" />

                        <sjg:gridColumn name="assignmentId"
                            index="grdassignmentId" id="grdassignmentId"
                            title="Assignment Id" align="center" sortable="false"
                            editable="true" edittype="text" search="false" width="150" hidden="true"/>

                        <sjg:gridColumn name="attributeId"
                            index="grdattributeId" id="grdattributeId"
                            title="Attribute Id" align="center" sortable="false"
                            editable="true" edittype="text" search="false" width="150" hidden="true"/>

                        <sjg:gridColumn name="attributeTypeId"
                            index="grdattributeTypeId" id="grdattributeTypeId"
                            title="Attribute Type Id" align="center" sortable="false"
                            editable="true" edittype="text" search="false" width="150" hidden="true"/>

                    </sjg:grid>
```

When we click a + icon in the bottom bar of the grid , which opens a form to enter the grid data and save, I wanted a 2 more dropdown value

```
<s:url id="attributeTypeUrl" action="getAttributeTypesList" />
                        <sj:select id="selectedAttributeType" name="selectedAttributeType"
                            href="%{attributeTypeUrl}" dataType="json"
                            formIds="attributeSetupForm" onChangeTopics="reloadAttributeList"
                            reloadTopics="reloadAttributeTypeList" requiredPosition="left"
                            labelposition="left" headerKey="0"
                            headerValue="Add Attribute Type" listKey="typeIdStr"
                            listValue="displayName" list="attributeTypeList"
                            onchange="displayAttribute()" cssStyle="width: 300px;" />


<sj:select id="selectedAttribute" name="selectedAttribute"
                            href="%{attributeUrl}" dataType="json"
                            formIds="attributeSetupForm" requiredPosition="left"
                            labelposition="left" headerKey="0" headerValue="Add Attribute"
                            listKey="attributeIdStr" listValue="displayName"
                            onChangeTopics="reloadAttrAssignmentGrid" onCompleteTopics="loadCompleteAttributeList"
                            reloadTopics="reloadAttributeList" list="attributeList"
                            onchange="displayAttributeAssignment()" cssStyle="width: 300px;" />
```

selectedAttributeType and selectedAttribute as populated when I enter the action method for editURL. As of now it comes null. How do I carry it to my action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I tried using , variables but nothing worked. What got me working is, setting a session variable and accessing in edit URL. Hope it helps anyone , who is looking for solutions.